# Which JavaFX visual layout to chose

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this basic visual layout of user panel:

Now to use border pane which I use to position the components but it seems that it's not the proper solution for my purpose. Looking at the picture which layout can you recommend me. I want to implement resize of the components using mouse border drag and I want to position tab pane on the full screen when I double click on a tab name. Having in mind these two conditions which visual layout will be appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

For a basic layout, I would have used a combination of two BorderPanes:

1. Top: Navigation, Left: Component tree, Center: 2nd BorderPane
2. Center: Table, Right: Actions, Bottom: Lower Tab Pane

If you want to resize the components with the mouse, however, you'll have to use SplitPanes:

1: Left: Component Tree, Right: 2nd SplitPane

2: Top: 3rd SplitPane, Bottom: Lower Tab Pane

3: Left: Table, Right: Actions

You'll have to implement the switch to 'fullscreen' yourself, it doesn't come with the layout. It should be fairly easy, however, by just setting the other components to visible=false.

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is a docking framework. Even though there are many Swing-based ones, I don't know of any good one for JavaFX. At some point one can appear in [ControlsFX project](https://bitbucket.org/JonathanGiles/controlsfx) - the work on it has started.